# Extending discriminated union of plain objects defined in library package in code using that read-only lib

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have a library that writes plain JS objects to storage. Those objects all have types. I use a discriminated union with a common `"type"` property.

The problem is that code that uses that library (then under `node_modules/`) cannot update the union.

I just switched the project from Flow to TypeScript. In Flow I "solved" it by providing a global type in `flow-typed/`. I had an empty global type within the library code's `flow-typed/` directory, but that is overwritten (the whole file ignored, actually) by the apps own `flow-typed/` global definitions.

However, in TypeScript I don't think I can have both an (empty) local type, one to include in the union type definition, that is later overwritten by the app?

I read through quite a few similar questions, but they were always a bit off and the proposed solutions would not work, or maybe I just don't understand how to rewrite them for my case. One difference is that my own use case seems to be even more simple: no classes, nothing fancy at all, just a bunch of *plain JavaScript objects*.

[Here is a playground link with an example approach (which fails).](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20LIBRARY%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Core%20(plain)%20object%20types%20defined%20within%20the%20library%20itself%20%0D%0Ainterface%20O1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'O1'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20O2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'O2'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20O3%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'O3'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Possible%20approach%3A%20A%20generic%20type%20that%20the%20app%20code%20can%20use%2C%20directly%20and%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20with%20type%20param%20or%20indirectly%20to%20extend%20an%20interface%20from%3F%20%0D%0Ainterface%20Ogeneric%3CT%20extends%20string%20%3D%20never%3E%20extends%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Ogeneric%20does%20nothing%2C%20sadly%20(I%20know%2C%20just%20illustrating%20an%20approach)%0D%0Atype%20oUnion%20%3D%20Ogeneric%20%7C%20O1%20%7C%20O2%20%7C%20O3%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Let's%20have%20a%20function%20to%20test%20the%20union%20on%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20libraryFn%3CT%20extends%20oUnion%3E(p%3A%20T)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Works%20(good)%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20a%20%7D%20%3D%20libraryFn(%7B%20type%3A%20'O3'%2C%20a%3A%2042%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Doesn't%20work%20(good)%0D%0AlibraryFn(%7B%20type%3A%20'noSuchType'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20CODE%20THAT%20USES%20LIBRARY%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0Aconst%20o%3A%20Ogeneric%3C'myType'%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'myType'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cc%3A%20'cc'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20%7Bbool%7D%20%3D%20libraryFn(%7B%20type%3A%20'myType'%2C%20bool%3A%2042%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

Here is code slightly different from the example, not showing an attempted approach but only what's there:

```js
// ============================================================
// LIBRARY
// ============================================================

// Core (plain) object types defined within the library itself 
interface O1 {
    type: 'O1';
    a: string;
}
interface O2 {
    type: 'O2';
    b: number;
}

type oUnion = O1 | O2;

// Let's have a function to test the union on
declare function libraryFn<T extends oUnion>(p: T): T;

// Works (good)
const { b } = libraryFn({ type: 'O', b: 42 });
// Doesn't work (good)
libraryFn({ type: 'noSuchType' });

// ============================================================
// CODE THAT USES LIBRARY
// ============================================================

// HOW DO I ADD THIS TO THE UNION?
interface MyType {
    type: 'myO1';
    someProp: string;
}

const o: MyType = { type: 'myO1', someProp: 'a word' };
const {someProp} = libraryFn(o);
```

Unfortunately the approach, using a generic member, used in that example does not work.

I could of course make it work rather easily by including a generic union member, but that would make the entire discriminated union useless. Right now, when a function accepting the union gets one specific union member its exact member type is reflected in the return type. So if a member is of type `"Person"`, with an `email` property, than the type checker knows that the returned object will have an `email` property because it can decide which exact member of the union is being used here.

I experimented with a lot of approaches, and all I managed to achieve was ever increasing complexity but no solution. The hacky approach I used with Flow, overwriting a globally defined type variable in the app, seems to be the least wacky one but a) I don't know how to do the same in TS, b) I don't know if there are better ones?

Comment: The library hardcodes the union type, expects users of the library to pass in a value of that type, and you want to *widen* (not extend) the union in your own code?  How does the library know what to do with something that doesn't conform to the type it expects?  Is the library actually intended to accept wider types than it declares? If so, it is not typed properly and its type definitions should be altered (e.g., make changes upstream to make it customizable by users, or you can keep your own local modified version of the library typings).

Comment: @jcalz I know you repeat an answer you give elsewhere in a similar issue I read. What I want to do is save the object. All the core lib needs is to know the type, then it uses recipes also defined by the app (the core lib has recipes for its own types) to create a storage version (cannot simply `stringify` for reason I won't go into). If the recipe exists is a runtime check, if the object type is correct a static check. The lib does not need to know anything about the object apart form being able to access its `type` property and then look that up in the recipes.

Comment: @jcalz  > *If so, it is not typed properly* -- Since the lib does not need to know anything about the object's structure it *is* typed correctly. The type information is *for the app*. Both the lib as well as the app code use those objects - but different kinds of objects, for their own purposes. The lib does not need to understand the ones of the app, the app does not need to understand the ones of the lib (but can if it wants). The lib uses its generic algorithms in generic data and does not care what it is. But the app, when it hands a certain app type to a lib function, cares about return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to modify the library's type definitions (either getting such changes made upstream, or, more likely, using a locally altered version of the library's definitions), you can make the `oUnion` type configurable by users of the library (assuming the library at runtime can actually handle arbitrary values and not just those of types the library knows about).

Often you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to customize types provided by a library.  But declaration merging can only *extend* interfaces, meaning it can add new properties/methods and make these types more *specific* by *narrowing* them.  What you're trying to do is take the `oUnion` type and make it more *general* by *widening* it.  This is not supported directly by declaration merging.  Furthermore, `oUnion` is a type alias which are also not alterable by declaration merging, even if you wanted to narrow it.

Luckily, you can refactor the code to expose an interface from which `oUnion` is derived, and you can merge new properties into that interface which will cause `oUnion` to be widened in the way you expect.  Here's an example.

The library code would look like this:

```
module Library {
    // Core (plain) object types defined within the library itself 
    export interface O1 {
        type: 'O1';
        a: string;
    }
    export interface O2 {
        type: 'O2';
        b: number;
    }
    export interface O3 {
        type: 'O3';
        a: number;
    }
    // here's the interface you should merge stuff into
    export interface SupportedInterfaces {
        O1: O1,
        O2: O2,
        O3: O3
    }

    export type oUnion = SupportedInterfaces[keyof SupportedInterfaces];

    // Let's have a function to test the union on
    export declare function libraryFn<T extends oUnion>(p: T): T;

}
```

And then the users of the library would merge into the `SupportedInterfaces` declaration:

```
// Works (good)
const { a } = Library.libraryFn({ type: 'O3', a: 42 });
// Doesn't work (good)
Library.libraryFn({ type: 'noSuchType' });

// use declaration merging:
module Library {
    export interface SupportedInterfaces {
        OMyType: { type: 'myType', cc: 'cc' };
    }
}

Library.libraryFn({ type: 'myType', cc: "cc" }); // okay
Library.libraryFn({ type: 'myType', cc: "nope" }); // error, incompatible
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F**%20Library%20**%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Amodule%20Library%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Core%20(plain)%20object%20types%20defined%20within%20the%20library%20itself%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20O1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'O1'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20O2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'O2'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20O3%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'O3'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20here's%20the%20interface%20you%20should%20merge%20stuff%20into%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20SupportedInterfaces%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20O1%3A%20O1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20O2%3A%20O2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20O3%3A%20O3%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20type%20oUnion%20%3D%20SupportedInterfaces%5Bkeyof%20SupportedInterfaces%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Let's%20have%20a%20function%20to%20test%20the%20union%20on%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20declare%20function%20libraryFn%3CT%20extends%20oUnion%3E(p%3A%20T)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F*%20User%20*%2F%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Works%20(good)%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20a%20%7D%20%3D%20Library.libraryFn(%7B%20type%3A%20'O3'%2C%20a%3A%2042%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Doesn't%20work%20(good)%0D%0ALibrary.libraryFn(%7B%20type%3A%20'noSuchType'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20use%20declaration%20merging%3A%0D%0Amodule%20Library%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20SupportedInterfaces%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OMyType%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20'myType'%2C%20cc%3A%20'cc'%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ALibrary.libraryFn(%7B%20type%3A%20'myType'%2C%20cc%3A%20%22cc%22%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%0D%0ALibrary.libraryFn(%7B%20type%3A%20'myType'%2C%20cc%3A%20%22nope%22%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%2C%20incompatible)

Hope that gives you a possible way forward.  Good luck!

Comment: Interesting suggestion; I'll experiment with that! I had considered somehow involving declaration merging but only had ideas for using the keys, so I was missing the actual object interface definitions and only had the type strings. Your example also provides those.